# I need a view which will contain columns, CatId and Flag . Flag will be 1 if there exist any subcategory for CatID

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

There are two tables: `Category` and `CatID | CatName`.

```
|   | CatID | CategoryName       |
|---|-------|--------------------|
| 1 | 1021  | Home               |
| 2 | 1022  | Corporate          |
| 3 | 1023  | Products           |
| 4 | 1024  | Gardens            |
| 5 | 1025  | Investor Relations |
| 6 | 1026  | News & Events      |
| 7 | 1027  | Contact Us         |
```

and `SubCategory` and `SubID | CatID`

```
|    | SubID | CatID |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 |    9  |  1025 |
|  2 |    5  |  1022 |
|  3 |    6  |  1022 |
|  4 |   10  |  1025 |
|  5 |   11  |  1025 |
|  6 |   12  |  1025 |
|  7 |   13  |  1025 |
|  8 |   14  |  1025 |
|  9 |   15  |  1025 |
| 10 |   16  |  1026 |
| 11 |   17  |  1026 |
| 12 |    7  |  1022 |
| 13 |    8  |  1022 |
| 14 |   18  |  1023 |
```

I want to get a view, in which there will be two columns `View` and `CatID | Flag`, where `0` if no subcategory for that `CatId` else `1`.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?, also what have you tried so far?

Comment: I removed the contradicting MySql and MS SQL Server tags - please re-add only the relevant one.

Comment: Sql Server problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd count the subcategories and left-join on that:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT c.CatId, CASE WHEN cnt IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag
FROM   Categoery c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   CatId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     SubCategory
           GROUP BY CatId) s ON c.CatId = s.CatId
```